# RESTful Response when the POST request results in the creation of different kind of resources?

Tags: api, rest, api-design

I have been working on designing an API that lets client create a product (think of product as something like website domain, something that comes into existence when client makes order for it to the service). Correspondingly with every purchase results in creation of the order object. Which means creation of two resources via a single POST request.

So afaik, the RFC standards recommends sending `201` on resource creation with URI for the resource in the `Location` header. But in the above scenario, we are creating two resources, domains and orders and I would want response to contain information related to both the resources.

Response would look something similar to this

```
POST /domains/
Request 
 body: {"domain_name": "awesome.com"},

Response
 Body: {"order_id": "1234"}
 Headers: 
   Location: http://example.com/awesome.com
```

But does not look very RESTful. I was wondering if there was a RESTful way to do this?

Comment: The first created object is Order. What is the second one? Didn't get it from the question.

Comment: if you want to treat Location as a resource, you need to change your rest URL design. The creation of a domain can't result in the creation of a different resource, that's why you should expose a /domain/id/location resource in order to post your request there. If you want to get domains Dtos with a subresource included that is a possibility, but you should avoid to creating multiple resource in that way

Comment: @cassandrad, the parent resource being created is a `domain` object (like awesome.com) and as a consequence `order` resource is being created too, which would indicate that you purchased a domain from the service. ( This is a little out of scope of the question but will give better clarity: The order object is generated for any transaction you make with the host, can be domain renewal etc. So it's not just tied to the purchase of the domain but also other things).

Comment: @Zinov, i don't think treating location as a resource would be a very good idea since there it just represents the URI where you can make a GET request to view the created resource information.

Comment: sorry @AdityaKumarGupta I was referring to the orders if you are implementing REST and you have HATEOAS included that it's fine, but you should avoid creating 2 different resources at the same time, Location in your case is just the link to the operations you can do over a particular resource, like GET/.... a hyperlink exactly to make your API more discoverable. In order to do that you want you to need to aggregate the location data you are getting from this 2 resources, I don't recommend to put that information on the headers, try to consider to return it as part of your DTOs

Answer (score 2):

RFC 7231, [section 6.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2)

> The 201 (Created) status code indicates that the request has been fulfilled and has resulted in one or more new resources being created.  The primary resource created by the request is identified by either a Location header field in the response or, if no Location field is received, by the effective request URI.

> The 201 response payload typically describes and links to the resource(s) created.

In other words, on the web we would solve your riddle by returning an HTML document that includes hyperlinks to all of the created resources, along with text to describe each, so that the client would know which new identifiers are available.

To make such a response machine readable, we would do the work of documenting the schema of the message, so that specialized clients would know how to identify the semantics of each of the provided links.

The same idea works if you replace HTML with a different media type (for example application/json).  You define the schema, and then specialized clients can parse the response to find the identifiers that they need.

Of course, REST is largely about standardizing things so that we can use general purpose components; `application/json` is somewhat inadequate here, as it doesn't include a URI type (just strings, which are too general).  So to be more "RESTful", you would choose one of the specialized JSON types that has a general purpose representation of a link.

Sookocheff's article [On Choosing a Hypermedia Type....](https://sookocheff.com/post/api/on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/) is a decent starting point for the kinds of questions you will want to be considering.